# Why is a kretprobe on sys_futex called less often than a corresponding kprobe?

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf, kprobe, bcc-bpf

I am doing some tracing of various kernel functions and system calls, and establishing patterns between them which can be used for certain performance profiling.

One thing that I noticed is that sometimes, even in my simple testing application which spins up a few threads which play with some mutexes, I wouldn't get any calls to `kretprobe__sys_futex`, but I would get plenty to `kprobe__sys_futex`.

I assumed that this was because e.g. a thread was calling into `sys_futex`, and going to sleep or perhaps terminating, but I actually see the same processes calling `sys_futex` multiple times consecutively without the return probe ever noticing anything.

I then assumed the issue was in how I was filtering calls to `kprobe__sys_futex`, so I made a minimal example using BCC/eBPF to test this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from bcc import BPF

b = BPF(text="""
BPF_HASH(call_count, int, int);

int kprobe__sys_futex() {
  int zero = 0;
  call_count.lookup_or_init(&zero, &zero);
  bpf_trace_printk("futex start\\n");
  call_count.increment(zero);
  return 0;
}

int kretprobe__sys_futex() {
  int zero = 0;
  int *val_p = call_count.lookup(&zero);
  if (val_p != NULL) {
      int val = *val_p;
      val--;
      call_count.update(&zero, &val);
      bpf_trace_printk("futex calls with no return: %d\\n", val);
  } else { bpf_trace_printk("unexpected futex return\\n"); }
  return 0;
}
""")

b.trace_print()
```

I notice that in all sorts of applications (a good example is mysql-server, which does regular futex operations even when idle - at least on my machine), many (often 10+) `futex start`s are printed before a message from the return probe.

Here's an example trace of the above program which I left running for a couple of minutes while I wrote this post:

```
... hundreds of lines of much the same as below
           gdbus-612   [001] .... 211229.997665: 0x00000001: futex start
  NetworkManager-541   [001] .... 211229.997667: 0x00000001: futex start
           gdbus-612   [001] .... 211229.997670: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-697   [001] .... 211230.789205: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-697   [001] .... 211230.789227: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-703   [001] .... 211230.789251: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-703   [001] .... 211230.789253: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-704   [001] d... 211230.789258: 0x00000001: futex calls with no return: 3994
          mysqld-704   [001] .... 211230.789259: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-704   [001] d... 211230.789260: 0x00000001: futex calls with no return: 3994
          mysqld-704   [001] .... 211230.789272: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-713   [000] .... 211231.037016: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-713   [000] .... 211231.037036: 0x00000001: futex start
         vmstats-895   [000] .... 211231.464867: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-697   [001] .... 211231.790738: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-697   [001] .... 211231.790784: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-703   [001] .... 211231.790796: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-703   [001] .... 211231.790799: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-704   [001] d... 211231.790809: 0x00000001: futex calls with no return: 4001
          mysqld-704   [001] .... 211231.790812: 0x00000001: futex start
          mysqld-704   [001] d... 211231.790814: 0x00000001: futex calls with no return: 4001
```

As you can see, pid 697, for example, seems to have called into `sys_futex` four times without returning in just this small trace.

I don't think this is a race condition in the eBPF code because if you mute the print statements and only print periodically, the count is usually bounded a few around zero for `sys_write`, which happens magnitudes more often than `sys_futex` (at least on my system's workload), so I would expect any race conditions to be exacerbated not solved.

I'm running Kernel 4.15.0-43-generic, on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which is sitting in VirtualBox.

Happy to provide any more context that might be useful!

There's a thread in the IOVisor mailing list which is relevant: https://lists.iovisor.org/g/iovisor-dev/topic/29702757

Comment: If you have the equivalent kernel module code that doesn't have the same issue, it would help to debug!

Comment: Sorry! - I'm writing a reply to your message on the mailing list right now; I was expecting to send it a while ago but I found the kernel module was dropping calls sometimes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known limitation of bcc (cf. [iovisor/bcc#1072](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/1072)). Basically, **the maximum number of active probes is set too low** for your tracing context and you are thus missing some return probes.

In bcc, the `maxactive` value (maximum number of active probes, see documentation extract below) is left to its default value. Since Alban Crequy's patch to the Linux kernel (cf. [iovisor/bcc#1072](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/1072)), it's possible to change the `maxactive` value when attaching probes through debugfs. That new API hasn't been exposed through bcc's yet though. I'll try to send a patch to that effect this week.

> While the probed function is executing, its return address is
>     stored in an object of type kretprobe_instance.  Before calling
>     register_kretprobe(), **the user sets the maxactive field of the
>     kretprobe struct to specify how many instances of the specified
>     function can be probed simultaneously**.  register_kretprobe()
>     pre-allocates the indicated number of kretprobe_instance objects.
>
> For example, if the function is non-recursive and is called with a
>     spinlock held, maxactive = 1 should be enough.  If the function is
>     non-recursive and can never relinquish the CPU (e.g., via a semaphore
>     or preemption), NR_CPUS should be enough.  If maxactive <= 0, it is
>     set to a default value.  If CONFIG_PREEMPT is enabled, the default
>     is max(10, 2*NR_CPUS).  Otherwise, the default is NR_CPUS.

Comment: I wasn't entirely convinced that this fully explains why I regularly have runs which seem to have next to no retprobes triggered, while some trace them reliably, but just realised that it's likely due to a number of threads in the system sleeping on a futex for seconds at time repetitively without other actions (looking at you, mysql), which each permanently consume one of the probes. That explains why I could only observe this issue with sys_futex, too (sys_write returned too fast on my system for this to become an issue). Thanks again for your time and effort helping with this!